# Bypassing Required Fields so just One Can be Edited on the Fly

Tags: fields, automation, email2case, required-field

I have some cases coming in via email to case. The issue is that I am looking to add a value to a empty date field without the need to add a value to other required fields so I can quickly triage as they are often time sensitive and there is automation on the cases that will escalate their priority based on this date. The other required fields will need to stay required for other purposes. Coming in from email-to-case they don't have this date so often users have to look up and find the date and want to be able to set the date without filling out the rest of the required fields so it is prioritized based on automation. Does anyone know of a way to make this a possibility to bypass the other required fields and just enter in the date?

Comment: Remember there are (with standard Salesforce UI and Object Model options) two distinct types of "required": required at the database level and this simply cannot be side-stepped, and required at the UI level, which can be side-stepped by using a different layout/edit page that doesn't mark the field(s) as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Case.Status` field values based validations, Like Let assume, You're Case record has been created by the `Email to case` on that time you just say that `date` field only required when `Case.Status` is *Open/New*.

After Your team processing that case (After it's assigned), they definitely change the `Case.Status`into other values, Then you can make the remaining fields are mandatory only when they changing the `case.status` values from *Open/New* to *Other* piclist values.

Please Let me know if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: The date field is the one that I would like to be filled out. Are you saying that it's possible to make all other required fields not required if the Case.Status is Open/New and then possibly if the Date field is changed and status != new all the required fields will be required again?

Comment: Yes, That's what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_overview.htm&type=5) to just edit that one field. As long as you don't have any fields required at the Database level, a Quick Action can ignore all the required fields on the page layout.